# Uploading >10k files as static content to GAE

Tags: google-app-engine, blobstore, static-content

I prebuild some static content for a web app which I intent to store on GAE. It has more than 10k files thus I'd like to upload that static content to the blobstore and use http to refernce to my static content from appengine-web.xml.

The problem is that the uploaded files are being renamed to some hash key as I understood. How can I approach the solution using GAE?

Answer (score 3):

You should use [Cloud Storage](https://cloud.google.com/storage/) - it looks that Blobstore will be deprecated at some point.

You can upload your files to the Cloud Storage bucket using a dev console or, a better option for that many files, a [`gsutil` command line tool](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/gsutil/commands/cp) with `-m` option. All files will retain their names.

Comment: But... But... It costs money :(

Comment: Cloud Storage does come with some free quota as far as I am aware

Comment: The pricing for Blobstore and Datastore is the same. And if you use "default" app bucket on Cloud Storage, you get 5GB free.

Comment: You know what.. If the prices are real, I'm going to be a millionaire with my programming skills. I hope I didn't miss some small letters... Gotta try to implement something to belive in it first ^^